# sed - How to get the first 2 sentences of a paragraph?

Tags: regex, bash, command-line, sed

Supposed I have a paragraph:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
>   the printing and typesetting industry.
>   Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
>   standard dummy text ever since the
>   1500s, when an unknown printer took a
>   galley of type and scrambled it to
>   make a type specimen book. It has
>   survived not only five centuries, but
>   also the leap into electronic
>   typesetting, remaining essentially
>   unchanged. It was popularised in the
>   1960s with the release of Letraset
>   sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
>   passages, and more recently with
>   desktop publishing software like Aldus
>   PageMaker including versions of Lorem
>   Ipsum.

Using sed, I how do I get a certain number of sentences, in this case 2 sentences, delimited by a period and extracting only the following text from the given paragraph.

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
>   the printing and typesetting industry.
>   Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
>   standard dummy text ever since the
>   1500s, when an unknown printer took a
>   galley of type and scrambled it to
>   make a type specimen book.

Comment: I take it you're happy you won't end up with text like "It was a dark and story night. Dr. Jones looked up at the manor house with trepidation"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/\(^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.\)\(.*$\)/\1/g'
```

Explanation:

`\(` start group

`^` match start of line

`[^.]*` match any number of non period characters

`\.` match period

`[^.]*` match any number of non period characters

`\.` match period

`\)` end group

`\(` start group `.*$` match everything up to end of line `\)` end group.

`\1` Replace entire line with first group.

Comment: That only works on a single line at a time.  What happens when you get to the end of the line and are at `"... has been"`?  How do you grab the next line in `sed`? You have to use the `N` command from `sed` to grab the next input line. This is why `sed` is hard to use. It is too line-based, and anything else is painful. It also has old-style BREs with too much needing escaping, and no guarantee that you have advanced regexes. Plus you can’t put comments in the patterns.

Comment: Hm, and why are you catting the file instead of giving it to `sed`?

Comment: Am assuming each paragraph is on one line. It is in the example.

Comment: +1 Nicely explained however one small comment, you do not need to escape the period within the character class as the only meta-characters within a character class are ^- and /

Comment: Ah, yes it's there in one but not the other. I'll clean it up.

Comment: Wow, everyone's sensitive today. I'll remove `cat` if it makes you happy.

Comment: Its not about sensitivity or not. Its about not doing the unnecessary

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Updated for some of the tougher cases.

This is hard to do in `sed` for several reasons! First, `sed` makes it hard to work on the standard multiline paragraphs we have in text.  Another reason is that `sed` is not standardized across all platforms, so you never know what sorts of patterns or options it will support.  So perhaps someone else can help you with that part.

But it is very easy to do in Perl.

```
use 5.10.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @texts = split /\R{2,}/, <<'END_OF_TEXT';
This is hard to do in sed for several reasons! First, sed makes it
hard to work on the standard multiline paragraphs we have in text.
Another reason is that sed is not standardized across all platforms,
so you never know what sorts of patterns or options it will support.
So perhaps someone else can help you with that part.

It was a dark and story night. Dr. Jones looked up
at the manor house with trepidation. Lightning
flashes could be seen both outside the house and
inside it, as St. Elmo's fire played across the lofty
spires. Mrs. Smith's fancy-dress party there on St. James's St.
was clearly going to be a lively one! Would anyone even notice
his mischief in time?  Dr. Jones chortled with glee as he scampered
up the step.
END_OF_TEXT


my $sentence_rx = qr{
    (?: (?<= ^ ) | (?<= \s ) )  # after start-of-string or whitespace
    \p{Lu}                      # capital letter
    .*?                         # a bunch of anything
    (?<= \S )                   # that ends in non-whitespace
    (?<! \b [DMS]r  )           # but isn't a common abbreviation
    (?<! \b Mrs )
    (?<! \b Sra )
    (?<! \b St  )
    [.?!]                       # followed by a sentence ender
    (?= $ | \s )                # in front of end-of-string or whitespace
}sx;

for my $paragraph (@texts) {
    say "NEW PARAGRAPH";
    say "Looking for each sentence.";

    my $count = 0;
    while ($paragraph =~ /($sentence_rx)/g) {
        printf "\tgot sentence %d: <%s>\n", ++$count, $1;
    }

    say "\nLooking for exactly two sentences.";

    if ($paragraph =~ / ^ ( (?: $sentence_rx \s*? ){2} ) /x) {
        say "\tgot two sentences: <<$1>>";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

When run, that produces this output:

```
NEW PARAGRAPH
Looking for each sentence.
        got sentence 1: <This is hard to do in sed for several reasons!>
        got sentence 2: <First, sed makes it
hard to work on the standard multiline paragraphs we have in text.>
        got sentence 3: <Another reason is that sed is not standardized across all platforms,
so you never know what sorts of patterns or options it will support.>
        got sentence 4: <So perhaps someone else can help you with that part.>

Looking for exactly two sentences.
        got two sentences: <<This is hard to do in sed for several reasons! First, sed makes it
hard to work on the standard multiline paragraphs we have in text.>>

NEW PARAGRAPH
Looking for each sentence.
        got sentence 1: <It was a dark and story night.>
        got sentence 2: <Dr. Jones looked up 
at the manor house with trepidation.>
        got sentence 3: <Lightning
flashes could be seen both outside the house and
inside it, as St. Elmo's fire played across the lofty
spires.>
        got sentence 4: <Mrs. Smith's fancy-dress party there on St. James's St.
was clearly going to be a lively one!>
        got sentence 5: <Would anyone even notice
his mischief in time?>
        got sentence 6: <Dr. Jones chortled with glee as he scampered 
up the step.>

Looking for exactly two sentences.
        got two sentences: <<It was a dark and story night. Dr. Jones looked up 
at the manor house with trepidation.>>
```

Hope this helps.  Every time I try to do this in `sed`, it becomes very complicated.
 Certainly you can only go so far in `sed`, and I virtually always need to go further than it allows me to go. If nothing else, I need a reliable way to know what flavor of regexes and switches will be supported, and you cannot do that portably with `sed`. Writing portable shell scripts is **VERY, VERY** much more difficult that people often think.  I run on these operating systems:

- OpenBSD
- Darwin (that means Macs)
- Linux
- Solaris
- AIX

The Greatest Common Factor between all those is so tiny, you can never get anything interesting done — at least, not portably — with the shell tools. It really is very frustrating. It’s amazing what contortions Perl’s *Configure* shell script has to go through.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk`

```
 awk -vRS="." 'NR<=2' ORS="." file
```

Set both input/output record separator to ".", then print first and second record `(NR<=2)`. If your sentences does not have arbitrary dots as in `Mr. James`, then the above should be sufficient for your needs without having to craft complex regular expressions.

Comment: An interesting solution, but still too line-based, I think. Arbitrary dots *are* quite hard, aren’t they?  I try to guard against them in my solution, but your `Mr. James` would trick me, because there’s a nonwhitespace character before the dot, then whitespace, then a captital letter. That is indistinguishable from a sentence boundary unless you make things a **great deal** fancier. It’s hard to get a 100% solution in NLP.

Comment: Yes, its difficult i agree. I think let's not read too ahead for ourselves, since OP has not given any other information yet. :) What is NLP? interget jargon?

Comment: ghostdog74: “Internet jargon”? Hardly! It’s a perfectly standard term used in the field of computational linguistics, amongst others.  Per Wikipedia: [Natural language processing (NLP) is a field of computer science and linguistics concerned with the interactions between computers and human (natural) languages.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) When text processing meets real language, there you have NLP.

Comment: @tchrist. Ah, i see. I know the full term, but not the abbreviation. thanks

Comment: @ghostdog74: Looks like I’ve outed myself as to my day-job profession, eh? :)

Comment: @Mr E: To the contrary: the example is not on one line at all!  It’s on six lines like any normal paragraph. Whyever would you call it a paragraph if it were a line?  Those lines each begin with the words "Lorem", "the", "type", "the", "with", and "desktop", respectively.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
 sed 's/\(\.[^.]*\.\).*/\1/' file
```

Provided each paragraph is on a separate line.

This might work for over newlines:

```
echo -e "a b c.\nx y z.\na b c" | sed ':a;$!N;/\(\.[^.]*\.\).*/!{$!ba};s//\1/;q'       
a b c.
x y z.
```

Comment: You can golf it down one, `\.[^.]*\.` can be `\.[^.]*.` because the only thing the next char can be is a real dot. I prefer escaping as little as possible, I'd use `-r` (or the portable `-E`), `sed -r 's,(\.[^.]*.).*,\1,' file`, even though the `-r ` is longer than the two backslashes it saves.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your example:

```
sed 's/^\(\([^.]*\.\)\{2\}\).*/\1/'
```

or:

```
sed -r 's/^(([^.]*.){2}).*/\1/'
```

Comment: What is `sed -r`? My *sed(1)* manpage gives this usage message: `sed [-Ealn] [-e command] [-f command_file] [-i extension] [file ...]`.  This is the problem with `sed` not being portable.

Comment: @tchrist  The problem is not so much that sed is not portable as that certain people who implement sed like to add non-standard options.  (IOW, don't blame sed, blame gnu or bonzini)

Comment: To clarify, I don't think it is wrong for gnu sed to implement new features.  However, I think it is very wrong that the documentation does not clearly state that the option is an extension and cannot be used in scripts intended to be portable.

Comment: @tchrist: `sed -r` is `sed` with extended regular expressions which is supported by GNU sed. If it is not supported you have to use the first version without `-r` and some more backslashes.

Comment: @William: There is a [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/sed.html) for `sed`. Perhaps there should be a way for all these things to warn about nonportable options.